# Set index col for a table from a CSV file without pandas

Tags: python, csv, indexing, datatable

I am to do a `Table` and was wondering if there is an `index_col` alternative in `python` natively. I have this assignment where the `csv` file is inversed and I need to make the last row the column labels. I am not to use the pandas library, only the datascience one.

[This is how the csv file looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pEbF.png)

Code is like this:

```
import datascience
Table().read_table(document_name)
```

Comment: _the datascience one_ ... can you give more details? Also show a __small__ example of the data and code you use to read the CSV so far. That will give us a starting point. You talk of "column labels" but there isn't such a thing in native python if all you've done is make a list of rows.

Comment: You can create CSV Dict Reader object. But field names should be provided when creating the Dict Reader : https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter
There are other approaches without using pandas
1. Creating new file inverting  the given file and read from it (so last row becomes first row in the new file)

2. Iterate and get the last row (labels),Then create and CSV Dict Reader providing label names (Created dict reader last row will contain the label values which need to be ignored)

Comment: @hasi90 how would you invert the given file?

Comment: @tdelaney sorry, I added a bit more info. Does that help a bit?

Comment: Is this the [datascience](https://pypi.org/project/datascience/) module from pypi.org? ... its the thing you get from `pip3 install datascience`? It appears to be a purpose-built module for a CS course. They have a [Tables](http://data8.org/datascience/tables.html) class that may be what you are using. I don't have time to work through the API, but generally to get the last row as header, you could read the table, reassign the column labels with that row and then delete it.

Comment: @tdelaney yes it is from pypi. Yeah, I tried that but every time I tried to assign using column labels it gives an error. I'm assuming that it's immutable.